# Angular5+ takeWhile is not a function

Tags: angular

I have this code :

```
public ngOnInit(){
  this.schemeStore.getSchemesByAffId()
  .takeWhile(() => this.isAlive)
  .subscribe((schemes: Scheme[]) => {
    const currId = schemes[0].currency;
    this.schemeFunds$ = this.fundStore
      .getSchemeValorizationsByCurrency(currId);
  });
}
```

I even imported the takeWhile with :

```
import { takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

But i have this error message :

```
ERROR TypeError: this.schemeStore.getSchemesByAffId(...).takeWhile is not a function
```

Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: You're using rxjs6 import so you need to use it with `pipe` otherwise change import to `import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeWhile'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrong import I guess, try with:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeWhile';
```